# My question is about using Nuxt.js with Wordpress as my Headless CMS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, nuxt.js, wordpress-rest-api

Im working with Nuxt.js and Wordpress as my Headless CMS but now I have some questions:

- Is it possible to get the menu dynamic and make all the links go to the dynamic page which I make?
- Must the SITE URL be the same as the Wordpress URL?
- Which Plugins should I use in my project to get all the data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can. Plugin for that is called “wp rest api menus v2”. It exposes menus to API.
2. No, it can be different.
3. “Acf to rest api” if you are using acf; Plugin for menus that i mentioned; “Yoast to rest api” if you are using YoastSEO. The rest is up to you.